# Powershell ISE setting a path from dataset return

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to set the path that I'm going to navigate to from a field in our database.  However; I keep running into errors regarding the | Format-Table command.  Removing the Format-Table does not permit the dataset to be displayed so I need to keep that there.  When I Write-Host $Path the correct value is returned but If I try to set-location $Path that is when I get the error:

```
The object of Type "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData" is not valid or not in the correct sequence. 
This is likely caused by a user-specified "format-table" command which is conflicting with the default formatting.
```

I've included the code I'm using below.  Sorry if this ends up being simple I'm knew to Powershell.

```
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "MyConnection"

cls

$SQLQuery = "SELECT setting, value FROM Table"


$SqlConnection.Open()
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $SQLQuery
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$DataSet.Tables[0] | Format-Table -Autosize
$SqlConnection.Close()

    foreach ($Row in $dataset.Tables[0].Rows) 
{ 

    IF ("$($Row.setting)" -eq "ArchiveDir" -and "$($Row.value)" -like "\\*")
    {
            $Path = "$($Row.value)"
            $Path
            set-location $Path
            dir

    }
    ELSE {$Path = ""}

}
```

Comment: What do you need to format table?

Comment: @Ramana - Because when I take it away dataset does not get written to the output screen.  Essentially I want to see the data from that table and then I want to pull the path from one of the columns and navigate to that directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I fully follow your question; but give this a try:

```
$ds = $DataSet.Tables[0]
$ds | Format-Table -Autosize

...

foreach ($row in $ds.Rows) {
    if ($row.setting -eq "ArchiveDir" -and $row.value -like "\\*") {
        $path = $row.value
        Write-Host $path
        Set-Location $path
    }
}
```

If you get the same error try:

```
$path = $row.value.ToString()
Set-Location $Path
```